# Xcode13.2.1 M1 build executable not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode13, macos-monterey

I ran into the infamous "executable not found" error when building on the new M1 mac machine (Monterey) on Xcode 13.2.1. I should note I am building an extension (not sure if that makes a difference), the build would be successful and the error seems to happen during installation.

[image]

I have tried the solutions from general google search and most are  mentioned on this other stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166924/xcode-13-executable-file-not-found)(non M1), such as:

- Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to No
- Check if my "Executable Name" is set to $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
- Check if my "Info.plist" path is corrert under the Deployment section of Build Setting
- Ran "pod install"
- Check if I have any missing file (? this one I am not super sure how but I don't see any "fainted" files when following this other [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934488/executable-not-found-xxx-app-is-not-a-valid-path-to-an-executable-file)'s top answser)

Anyone else running into this on M1? what is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the excutable address inside the info.plist file. Pls double check your info.plist files both on the ShareExtension and your target.
[image: info.plist]