# Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built. Xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I just updated my Xcode 13 to 14 version. After updating I tried to build and run app on my phone but Xocde is giving the this error. Any solution to this problem. I am using Mac os version 12.6 on Apple M1 Pro machine. For the simulator after showing the message build succeed Xcode stuck on waiting for attachment.

[image]

Here is the detail log.

Details

```
Unable to install "HTPlanner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-10-03 05:50:48 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001147e02bc DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001148143c0 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000104cfe57c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000114814144 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1196
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001146dfd10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2328
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000104e08864 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000104e092d0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001884a25f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001884a41b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001884ab8a8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001884ac404 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001884b6c98 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000188664360 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000188663080 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.0 (20A362)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 4572;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653081";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 1;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
Xcode 14.0 (21335) (Build 14A309)
Timestamp: 2022-10-03T10:50:48+05:00
```

Comment: what is mentioned in ```details```?

Comment: @Qazi, were you able to resolve this ? Can you share your solution ?

Comment: @saurabh Not yet Still finding solution.

Comment: @QaziAmmar Did you find any solution for this? I'm also stuck.

Comment: Update your app to latest version and then run.

Answer (score 55):

I was having this same issue. But I noticed that I had previously installed app on my device. So I uninstalled it and re-ran the build from Xcode and now it's working fine. So try to uninstall your app from the device completely and then build again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, you can check your bundle ID if you created a widgetExtension, the widget's bundle ID should be different to main project.

```
eg, main proj's BID == "com.banana.app"
so, widget's BID should be "com.banana.app.widget". ✅
rather than "com.banana.app".❌
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I installed app from `Xcode 13.4`. Then install app from `XCode 14.2` so this issue shown up. Uninstall app then rebuild works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a TestFlight build stuck on installing. Cancelling the TestFlight install fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can try.

First of all try cleaning and building again the project. If you're lucky that'll solve bit but I doubt it.

Then try removing `Pods` and `Podfile.lock`files and run `pod install` again.

If it doesn't work (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68946899/10339150)) you can set a new user-defined build setting in TARGET -> Build Settings according to the simulator you're using.[image: Target build setting]

Comment: I am using Package dependencies instead of pods files.

Comment: And second there is no option on VALID_ARCHS .

Comment: @Qazi, were you able to resolve this ? Can you share your solution ?

Comment: @saurabh not yet. facing same issue.

Comment: @QaziAmmar sorry for the late reply. Have you also tried changing the devices you're using? Also, try deleting all the Xcode profiles and redownloading them again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the `CodeSigningIdentity` from Apple Developer to iOS Developer.

Strangely...I only had to do that for the app extension, not the main app target.

Target > Widget > Build Settings > Signing > Code Signing Identity

Answer (score -1):

There are some things you can try.

[image]

Reduce SWIFT_VERSION from 5.0 to 4.0 (depending on your device).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it did not fixed the issue